# How to pass variable from jenkins to terraform

Tags: jenkins, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created a small project on GitHub with which I create an ec2 with tomcat on aws and assign it the policies relating to port 8080.
Now I would like to take a small step forward and

1. wait for the server to be active to be able to copy files
2. copy some sample files (such as index.html + a jpg) in the Tomcat ROOT folder.

The problem is that I can't pass the PEM file to the terraform part of the code. I saw some examples that put the PEM file on the git repository but I don't want to do this and I uploaded the PEM file in the Jenkis credentials.
What is the correct way to "wait" for the server to be ready and then copy the files?

Jenkins:

```
environment {

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    USER_KEYPEM      = credentials("AWS_USER_KEY_PEM")
}
```

---

terraform side

```
resource "aws_instance" "web1" {
   ami           = "${lookup(var.ami_id, var.region)}"
   instance_type = "t2.micro"
   vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-XXXXXXXXX"]

    tags = {
    Name = "myFirstWebServer"
  }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "cloud-init status --wait"
    ]
  }
    provisioner "file" {
    source      = "web/index.html"
    destination = "/path_to_tomcat_root/index.html"
  }
    provisioner "file" {
    source      = "web/img.jpg"
    destination = "/path_to_tomcat_root/img.jpg"
  }

    connection {
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = "?????????"    <-----how to pass pem file from Jenkins credentials?
    host = "${aws_instance.web1.public_ip}"
  }
```

Comment: You can define a regular variable in Terraform and then define a TF_VAR_name_of_the_var during plan/apply in Jenkins.

Comment: Can you show me better an example? What i must wrote in jenkisside and what/how in tf side?
I tryed this 
 sh "pwd;cd terraform/myfolder ;terraform plan -input=false -out tfplan  -var myKeypem=${USER_KEYPEM}"

but not work, maybe i did some error

Comment: Please do not post your changes as answers. So the key is located on the Jenkins server or not? If it is, I can update my answer, but it should be pretty much the same except the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way

In Jenkins stored pem_key_file

```
 TF_VAR_private_key_file = credentials('MY_KEY_PAIR_PEM')
```

...

```
 export TF_VAR_private_key_file;
```

In terraform

```
connection {
user        = "ec2-user"
private_key = "${file("${var.private_key_file}")}"
host = "${aws_instance.web1.public_ip}"
agent = false
timeout = "3m"
```